# Morris.js setData doesn't work, unless I do this

Tags: json, ajax, morris.js

I'm graphing data based on database results and getting the data via ajax. The graph is supposed to redraw based on the query using jquery setData. I've asked other programmers at work and still can't figure it out.

php code

```
if(isset($_POST['data'])){

        $data = $_POST['data'];
        $data = json_decode($data);


        $query = "SELECT * FROM bad_errors WHERE rel = '$data' LIMIT 20";

        $result = $db->query($query);
        $chart_data = '';
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {

          $month = date("M", strtotime($row['date_time']));

          $chart_data .= "{ month:'".$month."', website:".$row["rel"].", code:".$row["code"]."}, ";
        }
        $chart_data = substr($chart_data, 0, -2);


      $data = json_encode($chart_data);
       echo $data;

}
```

jquery code

```
let barChart = Morris.Bar({
   element : 'chart',
   data:[],
   xkey:'month',
   ykeys:['website', 'code'],
   labels:['website', 'code'],
   hideHover:'auto',
   stacked:true
  });



let json = JSON.stringify(rel);
  $.ajax({
        url: "ajax-php/morris-data.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {data: json},
        dataType:"json",
        success: function (data) {

        //data variable only redraws the graph if data looks like this -  

data = [
{ month:'Mar', website:38, code:547}, { 
month:'Mar', website:38, code:584}, { month:'Mar', website:38, 
 code:500}, { month:'Mar', website:38, code:564}, { month:'Mar', 
 website:38, code:500},
  ]
        barChart.setData(data); // but not here via ajax success
  },


 });
```

Answer (score 1):

I was processing the data wrong in php

```
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
     $month = date("M", strtotime($row['date_time']));

      $data[] = array(
        'month' => $month,
        'website' => $row['rel'],
        'code' => $row['code']
      );

    }

$data = json_encode($data);
echo $data;
```